# MVC5 - Checking for overlap between 2 Date (Textboxes) used to search against Date Field

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, validation, asp.net-mvc-5

I am currently looking into creating some search options to filter down my model results. I have a RunDate field which I want to search between using 2 textbox fields.

```
@Html.TextBox("StartDate", null, new { @class = "datefield form-control", type = "date" })
@Html.TextBox("EndDate", null, new { @class = "datefield form-control", type = "date" })

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Search" />
```

And my controller index task

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Index(int? jobId, int? page, DateTime? StartDate, DateTime? EndDate)
......
......
 if (StartDate.HasValue )
        {
            jobs = jobs.Where(s => s.RunAfter >= StartDate);
            pageNumber = 1;
        }
        if (EndDate.HasValue)
        {
            jobs = jobs.Where(s => s.RunAfter <= EndDate);
            pageNumber = 1;
        }
```

I however want to stop the search from happening if the dates overlap incorrectly eg. StartDate > EndDate.

What's the best way to do this? Do I have to use Javascript and add a validate() to my input click??

I have looked into [Request Validation](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/ui-layouts-and-themes/validating-user-input-in-aspnet-web-pages-sites) but this is now Obsolete.

I could also add a validationResult such as

```
 if (StartDate > EndDate)
        {
            return new ValidationResult("EndDate must be greater than StartDate");
        }
```

But I am unsure where to add this. So basically what the best approach to validate these form fields using the most efficient approach?

Comment: Consider using a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[GreaterThan]` or similar validation attribute so you get client side and server side validation.

Comment: yeah you could it by datepicker in browser. its the best way

Comment: I've looked into foolproof but can't find examples of how it is used with HtmlHelpers on forms. These two form fields are not part of the model so I have no way of using it as part of my validation

Comment: Then do it correctly and use a view model that includes those 2 properties, and post back the view model so you get strong binding and inbuilt client and server side validation and all the other benefits of using the MVC framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrap your form fields into a ViewModel, this model can implement `IValidatableObject`.

```
public class SearchViewModel : IValidatableObject {
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    // other properties ...

     // will be called automatically to check ModelState.IsValid
     public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) {
         if (StartDate > EndDate) {
             yield return new ValidationResult("EndDate must be greater than StartDate", "EndDate");
         }
         // other checks here, also yield ValidationResult ...
     }
}
```

And check ModelState in your Action:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(SearchViewModel postData) {
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
        // error handling, e.g. return View Index again (errors will already have been added)
    }
    // no error -> continue
}
```

A list of the errors can be rendered in Razor like this:

```
 @Html.ValidationSummary()
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, also added some javascript datepicker checks to stop the inputs from being able to select such values in the first place. Very much like the searchViewModel principle though, and will use that again.

Comment: Glad that this helped you. This is the standard way of adding server side validation in MVC. Also note that ModelState.IsValid will also check DataAnnotation attributes on the properties like `[Required]` or `[Range]`.